# Why is a constexpr local variable not allowed as a default function parameter?

Tags: c++, constexpr, default-arguments

I thought I understood why C++ won't allow a *local* variable as a default function parameter:

```
int main () {
   auto local{1024};
   auto lambda = [](auto arg1 = local){};    // "illegal use of local variable as default parameter"
}
```

but it's not allowed even when that variable is a *constexpr local*:

```
int main () {
   constexpr auto local{1024};
   auto lambda = [](auto arg1 = local){};    // "illegal use of local variable as default parameter"
}
```

however, a *global* variable (even if non-constexpr) is allowed:

```
int global;
int main () {
   auto lambda = [](int arg1 = global){};    // OK
}
```

Can someone explain the rationale for not allowing a constexpr local variable in this situation? It would seem the compiler should be able to construct the appropriate "defaulted argument" overloads for a function when that default value is fixed and known at compile-time.

Comment: You can make the local `static`, which is usually a fine idea except in a few weird recursive cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an issue regarding lifetimes.  Lets modify your function to

```
auto get_functor() {
   constexpr auto local{1024};
   return [](auto arg1 = local){};    // "illegal use of local variable as default parameter"
}
```

Now, at the call site of `get_functor`, you get a lambda whose default value is the value of an object that no longer exists.  Since the default argument is evaluated each time the function is called with no argument for the corresponding parameter, you need the initialization expression to be valid in all scopes.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just expected that a constexpr variable whose value is known at compile time, regardless of scope, would be a valid default argument since there would never be any ambiguity about the value used at any given point during run time.  But I suppose the constexpr local variable's is still coming on and off the stack and is relative to the enclosing function's temporary memory space rather than being something that's substituted into the compiled code (like a macro is substituted into the pre-compiled code).

Comment: @NKatUT Most likely this could be achieved, the compiler just synthesizes a global variable for us, it's just not something that has been done yet.  Someone most likely would need to write up a proposal to get the standard changed to allow local compile time constant variables.