# What is the essential cause for a local variable can't be a function default value (Error C2587)?

Tags: c++, local-variables, default-arguments

[Error  C2587](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2587?view=msvc-170)   `'j': illegal use of local variable as default parameter`

```
int i;
void func() {
   int j;
   extern void func2( int k = j );  // C2587 -- local variable
   extern void func3( int k = i );   // OK
}
```

I know a local function looks like useless. But I'm just curious why func3 (with a global default value) can compile, but func2 (with a local default value) can't. Why?

Comment: Seems like a decision : "Local variables are not allowed as default parameters." Maybe it has something to do with scopes and pointers. Since global values may be initialized in terms of pointer addressing but local variables will not be initialized until that function is called so no address calculation has taken effect yet.

Comment: I guess it may be related to possibility of evaluate this default value before call. Global variable is accessible and may be put on stack as an argument. Local variable is not accessible for caller so cannot put it on stack. But I have no hard evidence of it.

Comment: Answer to a slightly different question, but it explains pretty well why you can't use a local variable as a default parameter value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66325300/1863938